# IP routing to domain

Tags: ip, routing

I have a remote device that sends data to an IP address through a specific port. The problem I want to solve is that I need it sends data to a domain, but device only allow set IP addresses.

I want to know, how can I configure Linux in order to do a IP routing to a given domain.

Is that possible?

I could set up the device to address the domain's ip, but this IP address is dynamic. The domain I have is a noip.com's domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-part solution:

1. Using IPTABLES, you can do some PREROUTING to capture all traffic to a.b.c.d (the remote server), then mask that traffic and redirect it to e.f.g.h (your noip.com IP)
2. Using a cron script, running every N minutes, if the IP has changed, purge the IPTABLES rules and re-insert them with the new IP.

I haven't tested it, but this is how I would begin:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s [localwanip] -d [remoteip] -p -m tcp --dport [port] --to-destination [newremoteip]
```

...and the script, again proofing required (results may vary depending on versions and system flavour):

```
#!/bin/bash

NOIPNAME=yourname.noip.com
# Your IP on your WAN interface
LOCALIP=1.2.3.4
# The IP the software is _mistakenly_ trying to talk to
REMOTEIP=4.3.2.1
# The TCP port the software is using to connect to the remote IP
PORT=1234
# Just a file to keep track of what the last IP was...
REMEMBERFILE=/var/run/oldip.txt

# and now the magic, if it works...

HOSTLINE=$(host $NOIPNAME ns1.no-ip.com | grep 'has address')
HOSTLEN=$(echo $HOSTLINE | wc -m)

# Make sure the return string is > 8 characters (1.2.3.4\n)
if [ $HOSTLEN -lt 8 ]; then
  # Host resolve failure
  echo "Bad host"
  exit 1
fi

# Extract the IP from the return string.
DYNIP=$(echo $HOSTLINE | sed -rn 's/^.* ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/\1/p')

OLDIP=$(cat $REMEMBERFILE)

if [ "x$DYNIP" = "x$OLDIP" ]; then
    # Nothing to do.
    exit 0
else
    echo $DYNIP > $REMEMBERFILE
fi

# Flush
iptables -t nat -F
# and re-write
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s $LOCALIP -d $REMOTEIP -p -m tcp --dport $PORT --to-destination $DYNIP

exit 0
```

Lastly, add it to cron; the below runs every 10 minutes (via this part: */10).

```
echo "*/10    *  *  *   *   root /your/path/to/script" >> /etc/crontab
```

Caveats:
Now the IPTABLES will be tricky, if the command I gave doesn't work (probably won't - it was just a guess) - have a dig in google, for example:

http://ribbalicious.com/rewrite-destination-ip-address-using-iptables/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the IP address of a Linux system in the device. This Linux would do NAT (`iptables`, see `DNAT`). It would also check regularly for DNS updates and update the DNAT configuration accordingly. Of course, you may lose some data due to the IP changes.